# Why isn't the .sr-only class working in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, bootstrap-5

I'm currently trying to create a single page with just a form in Bootstrap 5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
          <label for="staticEmail2" class="sr-only">Email</label>
          <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="staticEmail2" value="email@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Confirm identity</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I open the webpage in edge/chrome, the email label, despite having `sr-only` class, is still visible.

[webpage opened in edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCeXv.png)

I've searched a lot and did not find any answer.

Comment: A quick search of [Bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/accessibility/#visually-hidden-content) for "sr-only" answers your question. That class doesn't exist in the library.

Answer (score 6):

This was one of the [breaking changes in v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#helpers-1):

> **[Breaking]** "Screen reader" classes are now ["visually hidden" classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/helpers/visually-hidden/).
>
> - Renamed `.sr-only` and `.sr-only-focusable` to `.visually-hidden` and `.visually-hidden-focusable`

So `class="sr-only"` should now be `class="visually-hidden"`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="staticEmail2" class="visually-hidden">Email</label>
    <!--                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           -->
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="staticEmail2" value="email@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Confirm identity</button>
</form>
```